# Find all polygons upstream of a set of points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, point, hydrology, upstream

Given two datasets 1) polygons for global river basins and 2) points for global hydro power dams; how can I determine the upstream basins for each dam?

Not sure where to start with this, looking for suggestions. I think I might need to find a river data set that can be used to find all branches up-stream of a given point then use that to select or id the basins?

Student I'm helping is working in ArcGIS Desktop, 10.5.1.

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being an online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Asking for ideas in the GIS Chat Room is always fine to do.

Answer (score 1):

As you have tagged your question as arcgis I suggest you read the help file...

There is a good introduction to the steps in [hydrological analysis](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/hydrologic-analysis-sample-applications.htm) that you will want to be using.